# Windows Script for connecting to remote SFTP server with public key authentication

Tags: ssh, connection, sftp, public-key, private-key

I am trying to connect to a SFTP server for a client of ours and send files in an automated process using MS Windows. The details I have received from the client do not include the password. I instead have the public-private key pair using PuTTY.

The typical connection string used is as follows

```
open sftp://username:password.SFTPURL:port -hostkey="ssh-dss 1024 XXXXXXX"
```

I do not however understand how to specify the private key in this connection, instead of the password. How do I tell the script where the private key lies and is there a particular key word to use when connecting using public key?

I am new at this so please bear with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the SFTP client tool given, or can you use one of your choice? Because if you have the liberty to choose, then I would recommend trying out [Syncplify.me FTP Script!](http://www.syncplify.me/products/ftp-script/), which allows you to write scripts like this, **using passwordless public-key authentication**:

```
var
  Cli: TSFTPClient;
begin
  Cli := TSFTPClient.Create;
  try
    Cli.ServerAddr := 'your.remote.host';
    Cli.Username := 'username';
    Cli.AddPK('c:\user_key.rsa');
    if Cli.Open then
    begin
      // Add your code here...
      // ...      
      Cli.Close;
    end;
  finally
    Cli.Free;
  end;
end.
```